# python variables in html / wordpress on cpanel hosting

Tags: python, html, wordpress, cpanel

I have a website that I am busy working on, which is a wordpress website that is on cpanel hosting.

The customer has some python programs that output information, which he would like to display on the website. EG, he has a program that gets some data from a few other websites, and does a bunch of calculations, and then returns a total. He would like to display that total on the website.
I was told I can put the .py file onto the server, but I am not sure how to get the output onto the wordpress page, or even an html page.
The one program has about 6 different variables it outputs, and he would like to display all 6 of the figures on the website.

All the searches I am doing are showing how to output html from a python file, which is not what I want. The website exists already, and so does the python scripts. I just want to put the information from the script onto the web page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: See [WSGI](https://www.fullstackpython.com/wsgi-servers.html)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.